# How to push to central repository in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, push, dvcs, tortoisehg

I couldn't find a relevant thread anywhere, but possibly this important task has to be asked about many times before..

I have a central repository, from which I have cloned to form a local repo. Now I made several changes and commits to local repository. Now I need to push/commit the final version to central repo. How do I do this?

I'm using TortoiseHg as the client.

When I right click, in the context menu of tortoise, I can see `Update` as well as `Synchronize`. I am not sure if either of these are meant for my job. If I select `Update` I see an `Update to` combobox where it has `default`, `tip` etc. Not sure what are these. When I select `Synchronize`, all I see are (confusing) options that deal with remote repository. Or does remote repo mean central/main server repo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can have more than one (any) amount of remote repositories.
2. Mercurial is DVCS (D - Distributed). Central/Main is just conventional repository, which all teammates use for intermediate code-storage (by agreement and workflow)
3. Synchronize toolbar (most right in toolbars, when enabled) is your best friend

   - 1 in screenshot is for actions-button for data-transfer (read hints for buttons /and THG help/)
   - 2 is section of defined remotes (in your case, after clone, you'll have only *"default"* alias), for which selected (by button) action will be performed

[image]

PS: from CLI it's a lot faster:

```
cd REPO_DIR
hg push
```

Comment: Ok I get it. Do you know what's the difference between update and synchronize? Update means update to what? What's this `default` shown in update window?

Comment: @nawfal - if you about "Update" in CMenu of changeset-list: "Update" here is GUI for `hg up CSET`, changing active local changeset of Working Copy to any existing in local repo

Comment: @nawfal, you _must_ read the [mercurial book](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialBook), or you'll be needlessly confused for a long time. It answers every question you asked in the first chapter or so.

Comment: @alexis I think I read it once, but I tend to forget/miss the point. Making it a question, would help me and many understand better

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit late but.....

if you are familar with subversion, think of (mercurial) update as a (subversion) switch...and (mercurial) synchronize as (subversion) checkout and/or commit.